# Trying to enter a Scanner input into my WebService to display outputs of what users entered

Tags: java, web-services

I am having some problems entering a scanner into my Web-Service skeleton. When I use the input Scanner command, it isn't displaying the results I want.

What I want to happen is when a value is entered for the `mySponsorID` string, I want it displayed in the response or the else statement. For example, if a user is prompted with `SponsorOrganizationalIdentifier` and they enter SOI, I want what they entered to display in the response.

I am new to Java and web-services so any help that you could give me I would really appreciate it. Below is the code:

```
package org.example.www.newwsdlfile3;


/**
 * ExchangeInformationServiceSkeleton java skeleton for the axisService
 */
public class ExchangeInformationServiceSkeleton {
import java.util.Scanner;

    /**
     * Auto generated method signature
     * 
     * @param hRCtoIRSUpdate
     * @return hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse
     */

    public org.example.www.newwsdlfile3.HRCtoIRSUpdateResponse hRCtoIRSUpdate(
            org.example.www.newwsdlfile3.HRCtoIRSUpdate hRCtoIRSUpdate0) {

        HRCtoIRSUpdateResponse hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse = null;

        hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse = new HRCtoIRSUpdateResponse();

        // get string
        String mySponsorID = ""; 
        mySponsorID = hRCtoIRSUpdate0.getSponsorOrganizationalIdentifier();
        // check if null
        if (mySponsorID == null || mySponsorID.isEmpty()) {
            hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse.setErrorCode("The update isn't complete");
            hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse.setErrorDescription("SponsorOrganizationIdentifier must have a value");
            hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse.setProcessStatus("Update Failed! Please try again!");
        // display entry for SponsorOrganizationalIdentifier
        } else {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        mySponsorID = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You have entered " + mySponsorID);
        hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse.setProcessStatus("Update Complete!");
        hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse.setErrorCode(null);
        hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse.setErrorDescription(null);
        scan.close();
        }

        return hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse;
    }

}
```

Comment: I fail to see what you want: A web-service is something that runs in a server and handles requests sent to it by a client. Usually the server and the client are two different JVMs. The User would input something on the client side. Where do you want to use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and for what purpose? Any data from the client should be part of the request (in your case the `org.example.www.newwsdlfile3.HRCtoIRSUpdate` object).

Comment: I want to use the scanner inside the else statement. So if the mySponsorID isn't null, write out what the user enters in side the else statement along with hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse("Update Complete").

Comment: I edited the code a little to give you an idea on what I want to do.

Comment: That will not work: Your webservice runs in a rack in some server room without any user interface, so the `scan.nextLine()` will stall indefinitely. What you should do instead is returning an error code and message, that indicates that the sponsorOrganisationIdentifier has to be provided. The best thing would be to make this a mandatory field in the WSDL, so it must be provided.

Comment: In the WSDL, I do have the sponsorORganizationalIdentifer required. As the web service pops up, that's the only value that is required. Is there a way to then print the response of that value in the reply?

Comment: What you usually do is logging the value. The most simple logging framework is JUL (java.util.Logging). Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html) There are better and more powerfull frameworks through, eg. Log4J, slf4J, Logback, ...

Comment: Can I add the logger and the private static logger import statement without changing the text I have now? Id like to keep what I have now and just add to it. How would I add that to what I have now?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a logger to your code:

```
public class ExchangeInformationServiceSkeleton {
    // define the logger
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    public org.example.www.newwsdlfile3.HRCtoIRSUpdateResponse hRCtoIRSUpdate(
            org.example.www.newwsdlfile3.HRCtoIRSUpdate hRCtoIRSUpdate0) {
        ...
        } else {
            logger.warn("User has not supplied required SponsorOrganizationalIdentifier")    
            hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse.setProcessStatus("Update Complete!");
            hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse.setErrorCode(null);
            hRCtoIRSUpdateResponse.setErrorDescription(null);
        }
        ...        
}
```

What still needs to be done is configuring the logger (log level, where to log to). It is usually best to do this in a separate configuration file and use that when initializing the application, thereby you use the same configuration for all loggers throughout your code.

Comment: Could you give me an example on how I could log this into the response of else. I just want to show the response to the client. I could add, "You have entered - Example" or something like that. Is there a way you can do that?

Comment: You have already done it your self in the if case of the if-else clause. If the `SponsorOrganizationalIdentifier` is a required field, it should not be possible to send a request with a missing `SponsorOrganizationalIdentifier` to the server.